# How to set git config in aws lambda

Tags: python, git, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to use git within aws lambda. However, `git commit -m "comment"` failed with the following error:

```
error: *** Please tell me who you are.
Run

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.

Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
fatal: empty ident name not allowed
```

I added the following code to config user name and email

```
git.exec_command('config', 'user.name', '--local', '"name"')
git.exec_command('config', 'user.email', '--local', '"email@domain.com"')
```

It failed with:

```
error: could not lock config file .git/config: No such file or directory
```

The reason is because there is no `.git/config` in lambda.

My question is how to set the git config file to a custom file in lambda?

Comment: While sometimes convenient, executing other programs via a shell or system call is usually not ideal. There are good git packages for Python, e.g. gitpython, which you can use instead.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using a config file altogether is to use `-c` like `git -c user.email='x@x.com' -c user.name='xxx' commit -m 'comment'`